# "Liking" individual comments in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I built a website for the fantasy movie league that I run (similar to fantasy football but for motion pictures) using PHP and MySQL.  Each movie's profile page has a place where you can leave comments and I have that part working properly.  Now, I want to add the ability to "like" individual comments but I'm having some trouble.  I think I have the "likes" table set up properly and I'm able to add a like to each individual comment, but displaying the likes inline with each comment is another story.

Here is the code for the "comments" table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`player_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the code for the "likes" table:

```
CREATE TABLE `likes` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`player_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `player_comment` (`player_id`,`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the code for the "players" table:

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`username` char(10) NOT NULL,
`password` char(32) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, here is the SQL statement that I use to grab all the comments for any particular movie:

```
SELECT comments.id as comment_id, comments.player_id, comments.date_time, comments.comment,
players.first_name
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN players on players.id = comments.player_id
WHERE movie_id = $movie_id
ORDER BY date_time ASC
```

My problem is, I'm not sure how to grab all of the likes for each comment in the same statement.  I want to be able to display each player's first name that has liked that particular comment.  So I want it to look like this:

- Line 1:  $comment
- Line 2:  $commenter_first_name
- Line 3:  $liker_first_name1, $liker_first_name2, $liker_first_name3 likes this

I'm able to get all of the likers for an individual comment like this:

```
SELECT first_name
FROM likes
LEFT JOIN players on players.id = likes.player_id
WHERE comment_id = 264
ORDER BY first_name ASC
```

But I don't know how to incorporate this without using the actual comment_id.

Hope this makes sense, I welcome any possible help.

Comment: Are you opposed to just LEFT joining the likes to the comments query, and then reorganizing/nesting the data on the PHP side, or do you specifically want to pull the likes with a separate query?

Comment: Doesn't matter to me which side it happens on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
SELECT comments.id as comment_id, comments.player_id, comments.date_time, comments.comment, likers.names
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT comment_id, GROUP_CONCAT(first_name) AS names FROM likes 
    INNER JOIN players ON likes.player_id = players.id GROUP BY comment_id) AS likers 
ON comments.id = likers.comment_id
WHERE movie_id = $movie_id
ORDER BY date_time ASC
```

The "likers" table should have something like:

```
| (comment_id) | Bob,Jim,Kathy |
```

For better list formatting, you can specify a separator:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(first_name SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you guys all so much, still trying to learn the best way to do this stuff!

Comment: If you want to do more with the list of likes, you might want to just loop through the comments in PHP, and for each comment, call your "likes" SQL separately, using "WHERE comment_id = ".$comment_result['comment_id']". Then you can get fancier with the likes, such as linking the player names to their profiles, or maybe just showing the first 3 names and a remaining count ("Bob, Jim, Kathy and 10 others liked this").

Comment: Keep in mind for a large system this could be problematic as there is a max size to the column, so if you are talking a large number of names you could potentially hit this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just add the linkes to the comments table?

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`player_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And then when somebody likes the comment, you just also add +1 to the likes in comment DB, not only in likes DB. And when somebody removes his like, you juset change the number to -1

Like this:

```
"UPDATE comments SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$comment_id'";
```

The problem I see is, that you want to show the likers...

So maybe something like this:

```
"SELECT comments.*, likes.* FROM comments INNER JOIN likes comments.id=likes.comment_id WHERE movie_id='$movie_id'";
```

Your select:

```
"SELECT comments.id as comment_id, comments.player_id, comments.date_time, comments.comment, players.first_name, likes.player_id
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN players ON players.id=comments.player_id
INNER JOIN likes ON comments.id=likes.comment_id 
WHERE movie_id='$movie_id'
ORDER BY date_time ASC";
```

The other thing is, that it will only return you the ID's of the peoples that liked the comment. So I would suggest you to save also users name to the likes table.

Comment: I think hes is going specificaly for displaying the users that "liked" a comment, not just a number of likes.